# Replace content between special characters using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

I have a paragraph as -

```
== one ===

==== two ==

= three ====
```

etc.

The number of `=` sign vary in every row of the paragraph.

I want to write a **`preg_replace()`** expression that will allow me to replace the **texts** between the `=` signs.

example:

```
== DONE ===

==== DONE ==

= DONE ====
```

I tried `preg_replace("/\=+(.*)\=+/","DONE", $paragraph)` but that doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^=+\h*\K.+?(?=\h*=)/m', 'DONE', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN2kG8/4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^          # Line start
=+         # Match 1 or more =
\h*        # Match or more horizontal spaces 
\K         # resets the starting point of the reported match
.+?        # match 1 or more of any character (non-greedy)
(?=\h*=)   # Lookahead to make sure 0 or more space followed by 1 = is there
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the `=`s back.

Also, instead of `.*` use `[^=]*` (matches characters, which are not `=`) so that the `=`s don't get eaten up for the replacement.

Additionally, you don't have to escape `=`:

```
preg_replace("/(=+)([^=]*)(=+)/","$1 DONE $3", $paragraph);
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/uJ8kM0/2)